# How does Ghost interact with Kog'Maw's passive?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I'm playing as Kog'Maw:

- Can I Ghost after I die to run faster before I explode?
- If I'm already Ghosted when I die, is my corpse still under the effect of Ghost for the remainder of its duration?

Comment: It'd be a very odd utility of Ghost, but if you could actually score a tactical advantage with that boost, it'd be impressive. I don't definitively know the answer, but if my memory is correct, you can't use any summoner spells other than Fortify while you are "dead", but that doesn't discount the second bullet point.

Comment: Pretty sure you can use revive too. -.-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They changed it in a patch; now, "zombie" champions lose all their buffs and debuffs.
I could not find the patch in question.

[Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51995/does-shurelyas-reverie-work-on-dead-or-decoy-champions) is a post asking a similar question.

Presently, Kog'Maw receives the speed boost over time from his passive, but Ghost will instantly vanish from the buff bar.

Answer (score 5):

He indeed keeps all mouvement speed bonus / malus after he dies. Meaning it works with ghost, but you also keep all slows that had been put on you.

Conclusion : Ghost + Death = keep ghost during passiv !

EDIT : With the recent patches, ghost doesn't work anymore with any zombie State. Meaning it will instantly vanish as soon as Kog "dies the first time". The same applies for all buffs and debuffs. Also, Kog cannot be target in zombie form.

Comment: I agree with **Dalshim**, it's impossible to use ghost when you're already dead but if you're under the effect of ghost, you still have the speed boost for the duration (as if you would not be dead).
It can be very useful (at level 18, kog's passive do about 400-500 true AOE damage !)

Comment: So in the same line of questioning, if you kill Kog and is being chased by his zombie explosion, are you able to target him to slow him so he can't run into you?

Comment: @Jay no, he becomes untargetable, I'm not even sure he becomes slowed by zone slows such as Singed's one. I'll have to check this one.

Comment: I Don't have points for edit the answer, but, Ghost does not work at the moment with any Zombie state. but it used to work, this answer WAS right, but right now is wrong. If possible someone add an Edit to this answer saying this, will be great.