# Does Shurelya's Reverie work on dead or decoy champions?

Tags: league-of-legends

Here are the different types of pseudo champions I was thinking of:

**Dead After Effects:**

- Yorick's Ultimate
- Kog' Maw's Body after death (from passive)

**Duplication Effects:**

- Leblanc's Decoy
- Shaco's Clone

Are these type of effects boosted by the speed boost from Shurelya's Reverie active ability? What about other activated effects that target champions such as the new Locket of the Iron Solari?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the awesome GraceNote helped me do some research.

Kog'Maw's passive suicide form is not effected by Ghost or Shurelya's Reverie. However, its speed does ramp up until it explodes into the acidic goo.

Shaco and his hallucinations (and by extension Leblanc's decoy and Yorick's Ghost I believe) do gain the bonus from Shurelya's Reverie.

Comment: check my answer about Kog, i tested that, and work, IF used BEFORE you die

Comment: @Michel In our tests, I used Ghost prior to death with Kog'Maw - I had 423 Movespeed when I had it active. When I died, not only did I no longer have the Ghost buff on my buff list, but my Movespeed went back to its normal value, and slowly crawled up to 418. So it didn't really look like Ghost carried over in our tests. Note that my exact values come with having 3 Halloween Movespeed Quints, so they may differ from a base Kog'Maw.

Comment: I wonder if this was recently changed?  Previously ghosting then dying caused ghost to contiune through Kog Maw's passive.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27302/how-does-ghost-interact-with-kogmaws-passive

Comment: @Toast i need test it again, now i am kind confused, i tested it a while back (like a month ago) and it work. +Grace Note Thanks for the information, can you tell me when you did the test ?

Comment: I think the move speed benefits you noticed may just be from his passive effect. It does climb up as you run around in passive form. Feel free to get back with me if your tests show something else.

Comment: @Toast There've been a number of changes to "post-death" states like Kog'Maw and Karthus in some of the patches in the last couple months since that question. This sounds like something we should do a variety of tests on, perhaps, but that's something that'll fit best in that question.

Answer (score 0):

Clone type skills **receive a bonus**

- Shaco's Hallucination
- Le Blanc's passive

Zombie type skills **don't** receive a bonus.

- Karthus' passive
- Mordekaiser's Children of the Grave (ult)*
- Kog'maw's passive.
- Yorick's ultimate*

<sup>*they can receive new buffs, but don't keep the old buffs</sup>

It worked a while ago, but they changed it.

I tested Kog; 350 to 374 without using Ghost and is the same using Ghost. 
Yorick's ult too, Ghost is not working anymore (with dead champ skills at least).